# CSS3 3d seamless transitions

Tags: css, css-transitions

Okay, so I'm trying to figure out how to make my 3d transitions seamless on a carousel I'm working on without transitioning the entire parent piece. I'm trying to create a cube effect that will be able to be utilized by as many slides as I want. Here's what I have so far, but I can't seem to make it seamless: http://jsfiddle.net/wDMHN/4/. Help!

Comment: What do you mean by "seamless" exactly? The fiddle you posted looks to work fairly well, but I'm not sure what your goal is.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve a cube effect, so it looks like a cube is just rotating. AKA the pieces are touching at all times.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start each side of the cube at its transformed position relative to the face, so one side needs to be rotate 90, the other 180, and the other 270. You also need to set your perspective origin so all of your faces are rotating around the same point.

Check out [this link](http://www.paulrhayes.com/2009-07/animated-css3-cube-interface-using-3d-transforms/)

It uses the keyboard to rotate the cube, but it would be a very simple change to make it autonomous.

Comment: That rotates the parent. I'm looking to rotate two children simultaneously.

Comment: I'm after the effect, but not the method of implementation.